# lumen, how can I not display the same name?

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I have the code if there is the same name in 2nd foreach, then the same name is not displayed, but I don't know how to keep the same name not displayed?.

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($respon_tel['item'] as $item) {
     $proyek = [
          'nama_proyek' => $item['judul_kontrak'],
          'from' => 'Another API'
     ];
     foreach($model as $m){
          if(trim(strtolower($item['judul_kontrak'])) == trim(strtolower($m['nama_proyek']))){
          // ????
          }
      }
$arr[] = $proyek;
}
return $arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the `nama_proyek`'s from the `$model` then you can check if the current `$item`'s `judul_kontrak` is in that set:

```
$models = collect($model)
    ->map(fn ($i) => trim(strtolower($i['nama_proyek'])));

foreach ($respon_tel['item'] as $item) {
    if (! $models->contains(trim(strtolower($item['judul_kontrak'])))) {
        $arr[] = [
            'nama_proyek' => $item['judul_kontrak'],
            'from' => 'Another API'
        ];
    }
}
```

Or you could get creative with the Collection methods:

```
collect($respon_tel['item'])
    ->pluck('judul_kontrak', 'judul_kontrak')
    ->map($f = fn ($item) => trim(strtolower($item)))
    ->diff(
        collect($model)->pluck('nama_proyek')->map($f)
    )->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return [
            'nama_proyek' => $key,
            'from' => 'Another API',
        ];
    })->values();
```